# Cannot launch eclipse rcp application in Juno

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I can't launch my rcp application in newly released juno, but it works well in indigo. I found  there are lots of lucene bundles were not resolved. But they were added to required plugins in run configurations.

Dose anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

```
!SESSION 2012-07-06 16:45:10.801 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=sv_SE
Framework arguments:  -product Myproduct.product
Command-line arguments:  -product Myproduct.product -data C:\Users\user\workspace/../runtime-Myproduct.product -dev file:C:/Users/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Myproduct.product/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2012-07-06 16:45:11.986
!MESSAGE Product Myproduct.product could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.106
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.106
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene.queries_3.5.0.v20120319-2345.jar was not resolved.

!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.queries 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.106
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.106
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar was not resolved.

!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.106
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.106
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene.misc_3.5.0.v20120319-2345.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.misc 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.106
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.106
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene_3.5.0.v20120319-2345.jar was not resolved.

!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.106
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.100.v201206081400 [18] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.help.base 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene_2.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.help.base 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.100.v20120521-2344 [21] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.help.webapp 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.help.base_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721 [25] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.200.v20120521-2344 [35] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.help.ui 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.help.base_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene.queries_3.5.0.v20120319-2345 [39] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.queries 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.queries 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.apache.regexp_1.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene_3.5.0.v20120319-2345 [52] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.misc_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.queries_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene.misc_3.5.0.v20120319-2345 [79] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.misc 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Bundle Myproduct_1.0.0 [171] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 Myproduct 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.101.
!SUBENTRY 2 Myproduct 2 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.119
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-07-06 16:45:12.128
!MESSAGE Application error

!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the problem by enabling a specific subset of the lucene plugins.

- go to you run configuration dialog for your plugin/product configuration (Run -> Run Configurations...)
- Select the Plugins tab
- enter "lucene" in the search field. It should display seven entries starting with org.apache.lucene*
- mark everything with 2.9.1 as enabled
- mark everything with 3.5.0 as disabled
- Click validate Plug-ins, it should say "No problems were detected"

Comment: +1 from me. My problem wasn't with the same libraries, but same error message. Using "Validate Plugins" was what helped solve it -- when there are problems it actually gives you a plugin-by-plugin summary of all the dependency issues. Very handy, thanks Silpion.

Comment: Updating the Run Configuration allows me to work around the same problem while in the IDE. But whenever I re-create the run configuration ("Synchronize" in the *.product editor) or when I try to "export" the product, the issue re-appears: Eclipse selects the 3.5.1 version for some lucene plugins, not the 2.9.1 version. I even put explicit version numbers "2.9.1.v201101211721" for the required lucene plugins into my feature.xml, and Eclipse still selects the 3.5.0 version. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved by choose launch option: all workspace and enabled external plug-ins.
[More about lunch options](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/launchers/eclipse_plugins.htm)

Comment: This approach only broke this more for me

Answer (score 0):

Hm. After hours of struggling:

This error can also appear if you have the wrong "execution environment" specified on the plugins overview tab. E.g. specified JavaSE 1.7, even you only have JavaSE 1.6.